# CakePHP, move_uploaded_file() does not work and I am not getting any errors

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to upload a file using `move_uploaded_file()` in CakePHP3.

I have used a if statement to check what move_uploaded_file() is returning, and its false. I have attached my code but I think I am using the function correctly.

My target location is ***webroot/img/work***.

I am not getting any errors.

I have changed dir owner `sudo chown www-data:www-data work/`

I have changed dir permissions `sudo chmod 777 work/`

I am new to cakePHP so I don't know what else I could try.

Here are my files:

***src/Controller/WorkController.php***

```
    public function add()
    {
        // Get file to be uploaded.
        $file = $this->request->getData('image');
        // Set path to the upload location.
        $target = WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'work' . DS;

        $work = $this->Work->newEntity();
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            $work = $this->Work->patchEntity($work, $this->request->getData());
            // Assign value.
            $work['image'] = $file['name'];
            // Move uploaded file.
            move_uploaded_file( $file['name'], $target );
            if($this->Work->save($work)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('New work item added!'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add new work item.'));
        }
        $this->set('work', $work );

    }
```

***src/Template/Work/add.ctp***

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create($work, array( 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
    echo $this->Form->control('title');
    echo $this->Form->control('body', ['rows' => '5']);
    echo $this->Form->control('link');
    // echo $this->Form->control('image');
    echo $this->Form->control('image', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Add Work'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot of information given so here is a couple things:

According to php.net on move_uploaded_file()

```
Returns TRUE on success.

If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.
```

So obviously it does not issue a warning, so it must not be a valid uploaded file.

Looking at your code you are trying to move the file name. When you upload a file via POST, PHP gives it a "tmp_name" which you can access via $file["tmp_name"].

So you should be doing move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target);

I am assuming it failed because it is looking for (myimg.png) instead of (asdagasfas.png) or whatever PHP named it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I have tried using $file['tmp_name'] and I actually got a lot of warnings.  1)`move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory [APP/Controller/WorkController.php, line 36]` 2) `Unable to move '/tmp/phpoGlYrn' to '.../webroot/img/work/' [APP/Controller/WorkController.php, line 36]`. I guess I will look further into these errors.

Comment: Ah! That helps a lot then! It can not be a directory is a big hint :). You would need to add $file["name"] to the end of your /work/ directory. So it would move /tmp/phpoGlYrn to .../webroot/img/work/image.png

Comment: @FrankTupelo Awesome! Don't forget to mark my post as the correct answers so others know!